# ManyToMany, persist only a part of the relation

Tags: symfony, many-to-many

I face an annoying problem.

I have an Entity User and an entity Job.
I have a ManyToMany relation between them, but the Table Jobs is already filled.

My user own an array of Job, but when I persist this user, I don't want to persist this jobs.
I only want save the links.

Do you have an idea ?
Thanks.

Comment: if you persist User what happen?

Comment: If I don't add the rule "cascade persist", symfony tell me that a new Entity (Jobs) has been found, and I have to persist it.